# rspec before and before(:all)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

here is what i'm doing.

```
describe "tests" do 
  let!(:user1) { FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

  before do
    user1.name = "new_name"
  end
  # tests...
end
```

it works, but the `before` block is being called before each test. tried to replace to

```
before(:all) do
  user1.name = "new_name"
end
```

but then I fail with:

```
Failure/Error: let!(:seller1)                    { FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `stub' for #<User:0x007f85477641d8>
```

Comment: Why are you doing this that way? You can override `FactoryGirl` defaults in creating process like this `FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: "new_name")`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just do:

```
let(:user1) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, :name => "new_name")}
```

You might not need a *before do end* statement at all

Comment: hi, thanks for the response. I know I can, i'm trying to save this unneeded action. if I have 20 tests, I don't want this to be called every time. just once.

Comment: You should definitely do benchmarks before going down that road. Using a `before :all` creates shared state between your tests. If something were to happen to user1 in one test, all of your other tests could be affected. Even worse, this behavior might change based on the ordering of your tests! In other words, always default to creating the state you need for each test, and only share state when you desperately have to!